# Objective-C - Factory to return a given class type?

Tags: objective-c, generics

With generics on languages like C# or Java, you can have a factory that returns a result depending on the given type? For example you can tell the factory method to return:

```
Book
List<Book>
Door
List<Door>
```

Is it possible to achieve the same thing with objective-c?
Can I somehow tell `generateObjects` method to return me an array of books?

```
[self getDataFromWeb:@"SOME_URL" andReturnResultWithType:[Book class]];
// What about an array of Books?

- (id)getDataFromWeb:(NSString*)url andReturnResultWithType:(Class)class
{
    // Convert JSON and return result
    // Mapping conversion is a class method under each contract (Book, Door, etc)
}
```

Let's say this is one of my data contracts

```
@interface Book : JSONContract

@end

@implementation Book

+ (NSDictionary *)dataMapping
{
   // returns an NSDictionary with key values
   // key values define how JSON is converted to Objects
}

@end
```

**EDIT:**

Modified the examples to be more clear

Comment: Are you actually trying to do something, or is this just a question about language features? Because if you want to convert JSON, there of tons of third party (and now native) libraries for this, and an array of strings is not the best solution.

Comment: Do you want to convert all `NSNumbers` in a JSON to `NSStrings`?

Comment: the return value is the first set of ().

Comment: I'm not necessarily asking about string, I am asking about an array of objects

Comment: So let me get this straight: You want to input a type, then get that same type out?

Comment: @CodaFi Yes, I want to input a type, and get object/objects of that type

Comment: Objective-C is not C# or Java with their generics. It simply hasn't the same feature. But it allows you to implement additional methods for classes which source code isn't available to change.
In your case you can use Book** and Door** arrays or construct lists by yourself

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is no possible to say that your array will contain String
But, Yes, it is possible to create String based on a Class definition or even a class name.

Objective-C as "reflection" capabilities like Java, it is called "introspection"

For example, you can create an object based on its class name using this code

```
NSString* myString = (NSString*)[[NSClassFromString(@"NSString") alloc] init];
```

NSClassFromString is documented here :
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/miscellaneous/foundation_functions/reference/reference.html

If you want the compiler to check types for you, you can also directly use the Class object, as this

```
Class stringClass = [NSString class];
NSString* myString = [[stringClass alloc] init];
```

Comment: That still doesn't solve the problem of returning an Object, or an array of that object

Comment: So ot seems like it's not possible to do this on Objective C. I ended up creating 2 methods. getDataFromWeb:andReturnResultWithType getDataFromWeb:andReturnResultWithArrayType

Answer (score 1):

Yes, NSArray and NSMutableArray store objects of type id, which means you can put whatever you want in there and return it to the user.  You just check the parameter passed in to branch your logic for generating the objects you are putting in the array.

Your comment suggests this is for converting JSON? To convert JSON you must have a series of conditions checking if the value looks like a number, string, etc.  So you could add a condition that says if the class parameter is NSString class then just assume the JSON value is a string.

Comment: Having an NSMutableArray doesn't help, My factory needs to know what type of objects to populate into the array

Comment: aryaxt, technically it's possible to make an object of input class. But your classes must have common interface to init object from JSON. Something like `id obj = [[class alloc] initFromJSON: yourJSON];` inside `getDataFromWeb:` method